# Why this variable is not an object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object.

```
fooBars = {
    foo: {
        propA: 1,
        propB: 2
    },
    bar: {
        propA: 3,
        propB: 4
    }
};
```

I need loop though it and compare the properties of each of sub-object with other variables. 
I want to check is the object has the property but it doesn't work. I tried to use some `console.log` to understand and get something like:

```
for (fooBar in fooBars) {
    if (fooBars.hasOwnProperty(fooBar)) {
        console.log(fooBar);                         //Display 'foo' then 'bar'
        console.log(fooBar.hasOwnProperty('propA')); //Display 'false' 
        console.log(fooBar.propA);                   //Display undefined
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8ayad75/)

What is wrong with my code? Why I don't get `fooBar` as an object but I can still access to his properties?

Comment: `foodBar in ...`? Typo?

Comment: `foodBar`? `fooBar`? `FooBars`? `foobBars`? Make up your mind.

Comment: If all typos are fixed, the third line logs `undefined`. See http://jsfiddle.net/cv8mdkj7/. The problem is probably typo-related.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, i'm not really awaken... I updated the question and add a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fooBar` is not object, it is just (`string`) name of (one) property inside `fooBars` object. When you got `string` value which represents name of property in some object, you can access that property value with (in your case) `fooBars[fooBar]`

Try

```
 console.log(fooBars[fooBar].hasOwnProperty('propA')); //Display 'true' 
 console.log(fooBars[fooBar].propA);                   //Display 1 then 3
```

If you do not believe me just type `console.log(typeof(fooBar));` and you wee see that the type of `fooBar` is indeed `string` :)

Comment: You're right, it's was a mess with my object name that's why I get the properties. I fixed it thanks!

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not a function, it is an operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix your code correctly. What are foobBars, foodBar, and FooBars? Those are confused.

However in this statement "for (foodBar in FooBars)"

'foodBar' represents name of variable. Not exact variable itself. This is difference between java and js.